# Не cчитываются данные с сайта

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Создаю мобильное приложение для расписания, используя библиотеку [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org) для парсинга сайта. Заранее подготовил код и проверил работоспособность, всё было нормально, но когда я тот же код постепенно начал переносить на Android Studio, начались проблемы. Конкретно не работает считывание данных (смотри ниже `Jsoup.connect( "..." ).get()`). Несколько раз специально переустанавливал библиотеку и пересоздавал  проект, но это не помогло.

```java
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContextView( R.layout.activity_main );
        TextView lesson_1 = findViewById( R.id.Lesson_1 );
        Document doc = null;

        try
        {
            doc = Jsoup.connect( "здесь могла быть Ваша ссылка" ).get();
            lesson_1.set( doc.text() );
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            lesson_1.setText( "Error" );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не постите код картинками - это неудобно ни вам, ни отвечающим, ни поисковым ботам; вставляйте текстом. На Андроиде нельзя выполнять сетевые запросы в главном потоке - нужно перенести запрос в фоновый поток, а результат вернуть в главный (так как UI -элементы, в свою очередь, нельзя трогать не из главного). Вот такая у нас свистопляска.

Comment: *"... подготовил код и проверил работоспособность..."* и затем далее *"но когда я тот же код постепенно начал переносить на Android Studio"* Можно ли более подробно о том где/как/чем подготавливали и проверяли код? *"... не работает считывание данных..."* каким образом не работает? В чём и как это проявляется? К какому ресурсу пытаетесь получить доступ? Что возвращает `doc.text()`?